# How to bind a parameter to child packages when they are dynamically chosen

Tags: ssis

I have a parent package which contains an `Execute Package Task` that executes packages using a `Foreach Container` through the `PackageName` expression, i.e. package names are populated at run-time. Each of these packages have the same parameter I want to populate, but I am unable to bind it since there is no package name explicitly stated in the task. I've set `DelayValidation` to `True`, but it does not resolve this issue.

So essentially the desired workflow is this:

```
Execute SQL Task to get list of packages to run, save result set to ADO
Iterate over each item in ADO, one of the values is package name, other is param value
Execute the current package with the parameter value from current item
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to execute package task and select the child package name from the dropdown(packagenamefromprojectReference) first before making the package name dynamic.

Now do parameter bindings. Once all the parameters are bind then go to expressions and select packagename and give variable name. This sets your package execute task.

Now set delay validation as true.